Is the "distribution" of a sequence enough to determine the convergence of sums over it?
The sum of reciprocals of natural numbers diverges.
$$\sum_n\frac{1}{n}\to\infty$$
Similarly, the sum of the reciprocals of primes also diverges.
$$\sum_{n\in Primes} \frac{1}{n}\to\infty$$
There's some specific proofs for this (particularly a great one by Erdos), but my intuitive "proof" is based on the distribution of primes. $n$ is a prime with probability $\sim \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$. My thinking is that

$\sum_{n\in Primes} \frac{1}{n}$
$\sim \sum_n\frac{1}{n} \cdot \Pr[n\in Primes]$
$\sim \sum_n\frac{1}{n\cdot \ln(n)}$
$\to \infty$

I know that going from step 2 to 3 and going from step 3 to 4 are right. My question is: is going from step 1 to 2 always correct? Can one construct a sequence who's distribution is $\sim\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ like the primes, but which results in the sum of reciprocals converging?
In other terms: is the average distribution of a sequence necessary and sufficient to determine convergence of the sum of its reciprocals?
More concretely, for a sequence $S$, let $\pi(n)$ be the total number of elements of the sequence $\leq n$. Let $p(n)\in[0, 1]$ be the "distribution" for the sequence if $\sum_{k=1}^n p(k) \sim \pi(n)$. Then is it always the case that
$$\sum_{n \in S} f(n) \to \infty \iff \sum_n f(n)\cdot p(n)\to\infty$$
?

I'm curious as to how one would apply this to, say, the sum of the reciprocals of the squares. We'd have $\sum_n\frac1n \cdot Pr[n\in Squares]$, which would imply that $Pr[n\in Squares] = \frac1n$.

Summation by parts seems like a very relevant tool here.
